# List to IEnumerable in a Async method

Tags: c#

I have a method:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<MyDetails>> HandleAsync(...)
```

Within this method, I simply build a list of items.

```
IEnumerable<MyDetails> myDetails = new List<MyDetails> {
                new MyDetails{ Name = 'John' },
                new MyDetails{ Name = 'James' },
                new MyDetails{ Name = 'Anne' },
            };
```

And then return the result.

```
return Task.FromResult(insuraceTypeDetails);
```

In a code review, I'm being asked to use `var` instead of `IEnumerable<MyDetails>`

However, when attempting that, I get an error on my return:

> Cannot convert type Threading.Tasks.Task<List> to
> Threading.Tasks.Task<IEnumerable>

I thought this would be fine, but the compiler will not allow it. Can I use var here? Or am I correctly explicitly telling the compiler what we need?

Comment: I'm not sure why someone would be _insisting_ on the use of `var`; if you know the result type, using it explicitly is clearer and, imho, better coding practice. The wholesale use of `var` is, I think, kinda lazy (not just mo) and can lead to the kind of problem you've encountered. My 2c: stick to using `var` in abstract situations such as linq and database queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In a code review, I'm being asked to use `var` instead of `IEnumerable<MyDetails>`

`var` will infer the type the variable from the intialization, in this cast a `List<MyDetails>`. But as you have discovered, you need the variable to be an `IEnumerable<MyDetails>` to match the return type.

You *could* do something goofy like convert it to an `IEnumerable`:

```
return Task.FromResult(insuraceTypeDetails.AsEnumerable());
```

or do an explicit cast:

```
return Task.FromResult((IEnumbrable<MyDetails>)insuraceTypeDetails);
```

but those are just working around a dogmatic coding style. There's absolutely nothing wrong with explicitly declaring the variable type, especially when using the *inferred* type does not work.

Use `IEnumerable<MyDetails>` and explain to your colleagues why `var` is not the right choice here.

Comment: I'd probably use `Task.FromResult<IEnumbrable<MyDetails>>(insuraceTypeDetails);` if I forced to use `var`... but yes, should be enough to say "no, this is not the type I need" should be enough to that CR comment.